# Android Persistent ListView recycling

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have been fighting with this problem for days. Looking for the solution on stackoverflow or anywhere a solution is given, tried all of them even tried recyclerView but nothing helped.

My PROBLEM is that I've a listview and two textView on a listItem. So whenever I click on list item, Visibility of one textView is GONE. But when I scroll down I see not only clicked one is gone but many others are gone as well.
Heres my code

CustomAdapter.java class

```
package com.example.nara.testtt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        list.add("item at " + i);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public String  getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv1.setText(getItem(position));
    holder.tv2.setText(getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nara.testtt;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CustomAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()` after setting the text update the visibility of the textview to Visible, since listitems in the ListView will get recycled.

```
 holder.tv1.setText(getItem(position));
 holder.tv2.setText(getItem(position));
 holder.tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//Your code.....
```

**Updated :**

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        private Context context;

```
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            list.add(new Bean("item at " + i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Bean getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Initialization .......

        Bean item = getItem(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(item.name);
        holder.tv2.setText(item.name);
        holder.tv1.setVisibility(item.visibility);
        return convertView;
    }
    // ViewHolder declaration 
    .......
public static class Bean {
    String name;
    int visibility = View.VISIBLE;

    public Bean(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the onItemClick on your activity.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Bean bean = Adapter.getItem(position);
        bean.visibility = View.GONE
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: `GONE` one will also be visible :(

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your comment. :{

Comment: I mean when I'll make the view Invisible, after scrolling down and again scrolling up the view won't be gone, it'll be visible.

Comment: if you want to maintain the visibility of the each view you have to create a Bean storing each item visibility.

Comment: Your solution will definitely work. Thank you :)
But I wanted it the other way around. All views were Invisible but only clicked one should be visible. I used a static variable storing state of that view and change that variable in onClick method. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the views are getting recycled in your adapter. So when you are scrolling the old views are getting used for the new ones. That means if the visibility of the items of the old view are set to `GONE` are still `GONE` in the new ones. If you dont want to save the visibility you can just set them to visible in your adapter:

```
holder.tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.tv1.setText(getItem(position));
holder.tv2.setText(getItem(position));
```

Or you store boolean values in a list or something like that and ask there if the item was clicked:

```
if(clicked.get(i)) holder.tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else holder.tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Bro I know problem is with recycling. I want to change only one view that was clicked to `GONE`. I get your idea but if I set visibility of only clicked view to `GONE` then again a few views will be `GONE` as well even if I use your method.

Comment: If you only change the boolean values in the list in your `onItemClick` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` it should work.

Comment: So you want me to add another view in my custom layout and store values  in that layout ? Isn't there any simpler solution? :(

Comment: No. I thought about it and I would suggest to you hold a Map in your adapter where you save your clicked status. I will update my answer to give you an idea about my solution. EDIT: Kartheek's answer is also a good solution. You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
```

with

```
convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item,container,false);
```